# Convert Markdown + CSS to .doc or .pdf

Tags: html, css, printing, markdown

Been using Markdown using Mou on the Mac alot recently, and would really like to use it in my technical writing - it is much easier than messing around with .doc formats.

The question is what is the best way to convert to a .doc format or a .pdf, i will need elements like repeating headers / footers, but other than that i just need the HTML / CSS to break sensibly accross pages.

Actually i guess what i am asking - is how do i print my styled Markdown output in a sensible fashion to .doc / .pdf in A4 or standard paper sizing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also generate HTML from Markdown and convert it to .pdf or .xls format using DocRaptor. DocRaptor also handles CSS better than competitors do.

Here's a link to [DocRaptor](http://docraptor.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the link on this one. This does the job perfectly :-)

Comment: DocRaptor uses [PrinceXML](http://princexml.com) for HTML+CSS to PDF conversion. Just in case you don't want to be bound to DocRaptor's Service.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/), [AsciiDoc](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/) or [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html). They're similar to Markdown – simple plain text formats – but have plenty of support for publishing to a variety of formats.

Comment: Pandoc is extremely cool, but you can't use it for Markdown + CSS to pdf, because it uses Latex to produce the pdf, and ignores the CSS. I suspect something similar happens with AsciiDoc and rST, and I haven't seen any non-standard styling using CSS with them either. I'd love to be proven wrong though!

Comment: Pandoc looks good to me. If on a Mac you can `brew install pandoc` with homebrew. Very nice!

Comment: @the0ther I've used Pandoc a lot since I wrote that answer... it's my go-to solution for Markdown to PDF conversion. You can control simple things like margins by passing in parameters and can do more complicated formatting (like adding a logo on the header of every page) by telling it to inject some custom Latex -- not quite as simple as CSS, but does the job.

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying this for technical docs as well.  The best tool I found to generate PDFs is [gimli](https://github.com/walle/gimli).  In our environment:

1. Markdown source is stored in a git repository on a central server.
2. Jenkins polls that git repo for changes on master
3. The Jenkins job fetches the changes and publishes HTML and PDF versions to the intranet.

Works a treat so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'm generating HTML from my markdown and then using [htmldoc](http://www.htmldoc.org/) to generate PDF files. Htmldoc gives you a ton of control over how your file formats. Not sure if you can get it to read in a CSS file as well, but the docs might help.

Answer (score 0):

My solution (for windows) was to install **wkhtmltopdf**, which works through cmd, and then call it in r using the r base command `shell`.

You can call it in r by the following line:

`shell('"c:\\...\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe" c:\\...inputdestination...\\htmlFile.html c:\\...outputdestination...\\nameForPdf.pdf')`

The htmlFile.html and the (htmlFile_files) folder containing .css file need to be in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [Marked](http://marked2app.com/) by Brett Terpstra. It handles custom CSS and outputs to a variety of formats, including PDF, with page breaks. It's not free, but it is great and worth the - very reasonable - price.